# Twitter API 1.1 User Image and name

Tags: rest, twitter

Twitter provided a great 1.0 API. I could grab an user image just like this:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/twitter
```

Does the 1.1 update give anything like this away for free? Or does the 1.1 update require authentication for a user image and user name? I noticed there is no equivalent call in the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

and this does not work:

```
 http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_image/twitter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the user image and user name with authentication.
If you're trying to get the user profile image with Abraham's twitteroauth, then I guess this [link](http://codedsack.com/get-user-tweets-php-twitter-api-v1-1/) will help you.
You can get the user name similarly by calling the name object and display it.

Answer (score -1):

You should find your answers in the Twitter API docs here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners

e.g: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitterapi`

and it does requires Authentication to retrieve it:

Comment: I saw this, and this isn't a user photo, this is a user banner

Comment: "You can obtain a user's most recent profile image, along with the other components comprising their identity on Twitter, from GET users/show. Within the user object, you'll find the **profile_image_url** and **profile_image_url_https** fields."

here is User object detailed description: [https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users)

Comment: it requires authentication