# Pull Twitter Profile Image in Twitter API VERSION 1.1

Tags: javascript, url, twitter, tweetsharp

Is there a quick way to pull twitter profile image in Javascript? I need to get the url of the FULL image (not avatar size). Thanks. Any code sample is good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter API 1.1 User Image and name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119558/twitter-api-1-1-user-image-and-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below, I am using Tweet Sharp:

```
While callback twitter is providing ProfileImageURL. Maintain this and again
  hit the provided url using OAuth, it will return Twitter user image URL
```

OR using below URL, hit with OAuth and get ImageURL.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=amit
```

**For non secure, it will return in `ProfileImageUrl` and for secure `ProfileImageUrlHttps`**